# Select Lists From Dropdown in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my jquery and javascript with this  i have a drop down from which i can select files.. so i need is that i have to select multiple files from this dropdown and placed on new div
dropdown placed on its default place and just i have to do is select more and more files and append to add_dd(div) with click on add more filter
this is my jquery function so pls tell me

```
         $(".add_more_btn2").click(function () {
             var abc = '<div class="slider_slect"><div class="fl"><dl id="sample_dc_1";><dt><a href="#"><span><img class="flag" src="images/select_arrow.gif" alt="" /></span></a></dt><dd><ul><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img1.gif" alt="School" title="School"/></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img2.gif" alt="Grade" title="Grade" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img3.gif" alt="Gender" title="Gender" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img4.gif" alt="Group" title="Group" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img5.gif" alt="Race" title="Race" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img6.gif" alt="Teacher" title="Teacher" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img7.gif" alt="Parent" title="Parent" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img8.gif" alt="Student" title="Student" /></a></li></ul></dd></dl></div><div class="fl"><dl id="sample2" class="dropdown2"><dt><a href="#"><span></span></a></dt><dd><ul><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li><li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li></ul></dd></dl></div></div></br>';
             var exist = $("#add_dd").html();
             $("#add_dd").html(exist + abc);
             $(".slider_slect").append($("#add_dd"));
         });
```

this is my html of dropdown and lists in it

```
<div class="slider_slect">
    <div class="fl">
        <dl id="sample_dc_1" class="dropdown"> <dt><a href="#"><span><img class="flag" src="images/select_arrow.gif" alt="" /></span></a></dt>

            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img1.gif" alt="School" title="School"/></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img2.gif" alt="Grade" title="Grade" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img3.gif" alt="Gender" title="Gender" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img4.gif" alt="Group" title="Group" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img5.gif" alt="Race" title="Race" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img6.gif" alt="Teacher" title="Teacher" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img7.gif" alt="Parent" title="Parent" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img8.gif" alt="Student" title="Student" /></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="fl">
        <dl id="sample_dp_1" class="dropdown2"> <dt><a href="#"><span></span></a></dt>

            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="add_dd"></div>
<div class="add_more_btn2"> <a href="javascript:;" onClick="addAnswer(); return false;">Add More Filters<span>+</span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: why u edit this question

Comment: did any one have answer for this Anton

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the way I understood it is that you want to be able to select items from two dropdowns and add them to another div when you click a button.

Essentially you need to find the selected item of both dropdowns in the click event of the button.  So your javascript would be something like:

```
$('#add_more_btn_id').click(function() {        
    dd1_selected = $( '#dropdown_1 option:selected' ).val();
    dd2_selected = $( '#dropdown_2 option:selected' ).val();
});
```

where dropdown_1 and dropdown_2 are the id elements of the two dropdowns and add_more_btn_id is the id of the button to add more filters.

To add that dd1_selected and dd2_selected to another div you could do:

```
$('#add_dd').append("Selected "+dd1_selected+" in DropDown1 and "+dd2_selected+" in DropDown2");
```

Comment: plz tell me something i m working on it from last 3 days

Comment: I edited my answer but you should really edit the question with some clarifications instead of only doing it through comments.  It will help organise the question for anyone searching in the future.

Comment: what is selected in this

Comment: $(".dropdown2 dd ul li a").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(".dropdown2 dt a span").html(text);
                $(".dropdown2 dd ul").hide();
                $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample2"));
            });


this is my selected file

Answer (score 0):

As far i understood your question, are you trying to add `values` to div once its clicked ?

This may help you.

**HTML:**

```
        <dl id="sample_dp_1" class="dropdown2"> <dt><a href="#"><span></span></a></dt>

        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Value Here</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
      </dl>
     <div id="add_dd"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#sample_dp_1 li').click(function(){
   var data = $('#add_dd').html();
   data = data + '<li>'+ $(this).text() + '</li>';
   $('#add_dd').html(data);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kv2tq/)

Comment: there are two type lists in one a icons and another a value here

Comment: Do you say like, if i click on icon corresponding icon and value should go to div ?

Comment: if i click on add more filter button then i select a list from dropdown it can go to div

Comment: on clicking addMoreFilter button, new sets of dropdown should appear or you select from existing dropdown ?

Comment: firstly,
when click on a dropdown a lists opened and select one from it and append to another div then i want can add more like this by select from drop down

Comment: i can select from existing dropdown not from new

Comment: i want to add both icon and value lists into div

Comment: can u give me u r email i can send u my screenshot

Comment: i have to select both item from drop down a icon and a value then clcik on add more filter and select a new one then click add more filter it can append to new div all without dropdown