# Append Data From Dropdown to new div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code and i need a jQuery code in which i can select lists from both dropdown and append to new div ....this is my dropdown in one i can select icon and on another i can select value here line when i select both i can click on button add more filter and it append to new div then select new lists and append to new div

```
<div class="slider_slect">
    <div class="fl"><dl id="sample_dc_1" class="dropdown">
            <dt></dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img1.gif" alt="School" title="School"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img2.gif" alt="Grade" title="Grade" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img3.gif" alt="Gender" title="Gender" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img4.gif" alt="Group" title="Group" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img5.gif" alt="Race" title="Race" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img6.gif" alt="Teacher" title="Teacher" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img7.gif" alt="Parent" title="Parent" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="images/select_img8.gif" alt="Student" title="Student" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="fl">
        <dl id="sample_dp_1" class="dropdown2">
            <dt><a href="#"><span></span></a></dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Value Here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="add_dd"></div>
<div class="add_more_btn2">
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="addAnswer();
            return true;">Add More Filters<span>+</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend if you can create a sample for your problem

Comment: Are you saying you want to select your `icon` from a dropdown, and also your `value`, and create an element with both of these values?

Comment: m nt able to upload a screenshot of this

Comment: yes i have to create this element and append to new div i named add_dd

Comment: ok i'll wtng for this

Comment: nicholas-hazel  any answer???

Comment: Yup, working on it sir. I assume you want these `values`? [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbnuV/)

Comment: yes same as but append to new div

Comment: As `classes` or........? I have the data. Your question was vague. How would you like it applied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Lists From Dropdown in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453124/select-lists-from-dropdown-in-jquery)

Comment: just like your fiddle i have to append it to new div

Comment: What do you want `volvo` and `blue` to apply to? `classes`?

Comment: i want when first select volve then select blue then these both come in a list

Comment: You want me to `print` `volvo` and `blue` on the `DOM` as a `li` element?

Comment: Answered. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

## I belive you are asking this:

## http://jsfiddle.net/mbnuV/2/

**Obviously, this can be taken into different `properties` and `values`, but essentially your `data` from both `value`s is successful.** This is a sample script and example in the simplest of context.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="cars" id="model">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>

<select name="background" id="background">
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="makeIt" value="Make It" />

<ul id="ourData"></ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#makeIt').click(function() {
      var a = $('#model').val();
      var b = $('#background').val();
      $('#ourData').append('<li>'+a+'</li>');
      $('#ourData').append('<li>'+b+'</li>');

    });
});
```

Comment: I will **not** write code for you unless you provide it first. Change your `li` items into `options` within a `select` `element` and see how it works. You won't be able to do this easily with `lists`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

add a id for both the list , `icon` for icon list and `val` for value list

**ICON LIST**

`<ul id="icon"> <li></li>.....<li></li> </ul>`

**VALUE LIST**

`<ul id="value"> <li></li>.....<li></li> </ul>`

```
 function extract() {
    var icon ;
    var  value;
    icon = $('#icon li.active').find('a').html();
    value = $('#val li.active').find('a').text();
    var res = '<ul><li>' + icon + ' <li><li>' + value + ' </li></ul>';
    $('#add_add').html(res);
  }
$('#icon li').on('click', function () {
    $('#icon li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    extract();
 });

 $('#val li').on('click', function () {
    $('#val li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    extract();
 });
```

**List of things to be done:**

1. add a click event listener for both the list items in order to set the list value as active.
2. Call the extract function to extract the active value from list and construct the data as a unordered list .
3. finally append the constrcuted unordered list to the div "add_dd".

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/NV4m4/47/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Not sure. Code looks clean. I think it's overkill for his question, but perhaps a random drifter downvoted based on the fact that you're complicating this a little more than it should be.

Comment: @anu: could you just check if everything is working fine,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/NV4m4/3/

Comment: @NicholasHazel: there is always room for optimization but that doesnt tag a code a bad code.

Comment: @anu: let me check that

Comment: @anu: i have updated the link,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/NV4m4/46/ . check if its working fine